# How to have each "results" (parameters) from API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

that is my raw response from [API call](https://jsfiddle.net/BMF_T95/5kqycpav/1/) who im trying to get each "bloc" result with a `.forEach`

```
const app = express();
const axios = require('axios')

jobList = [];

app.get('/getAPIResponse', function(req, res) {
async function myFunction() {


axios.get('https://api...') 
    //res.json(body)
  .then((result) => {
    
    
    result.results.forEach((element) => {
      
      console.log(element)
      
      this.jobList.push(element)
      
    });

  })

  }
 myfunction();
});


app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
 });
```

but the problem is, it made me some error on my terminal

```
(rejection id: 2)
(node:81826) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at /Users/mac/Desktop/alternatics_test/index.js:22:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(node:81826) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:81826) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at /Users/mac/Desktop/alternatics_test/index.js:22:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(node:81826) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)
```

to be as clear as possible `results` is the keyword in the api from which I would like to take each result block for insert in my "jobList"

I looked everywhere and the `forEach` seems to be the right technique for this...

Comment: I think you should log the result from your api, may be your result is null

Comment: @ĐoànĐứcBảo no because I tested directly that putting api url on the browser and I have many responce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `result.data.results.forEach`

Comment: Thank you very much it's working well

Comment: happy to help, please upvote the answer also :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using module [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

That will return a response with [axios response schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#response-schema)

So you have to get result like this `result.data.results` then you can use `forEach` function